# C# export of large datatbase to XML

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, export

What is the most memory efficient method for exporting several SQL database tables to a single XML file? I want to avoid loading the tables into memory (ex: DataTable or DataSet)

Comment: You don't have a lot of choices. You're pretty much left with a SQLDataReader.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" is not a duplicate. The accepted answer to that question loads the entire table into memory, which is exactly what the OP here does not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN:

> If there is no need for an in-memory relational view of the data using
>   the DataSet, the ExecuteXmlReader method is well suited for retrieving
>   XML data, especially for large quantities of data. Because
>   ExecuteXmlReader is a streaming API, it does not have to retrieve and
>   cache all the data before exposing it to the caller, as would be the
>   case if a DataSet were used to convert relational data into XML.

Which for your example could be something like this(using ExecuteXmlReader):

```
XmlWriterSettings set = new XmlWriterSettings();
set.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
set.Indent = true;
//comm is your command object
using (XmlReader reader = comm.ExecuteXmlReader())
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(File.Open("testing.xml",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write),set)) 
{
      while (!reader.EOF)
      {
          writer.WriteStartElement("test");
          writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
          writer.WriteEndElement();
      }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. The `FOR XML` clause in the query automatically formats the result as XML?

Comment: yes it does jim but with a simple hierarchy, for more please refer to this msdn link please - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188273.aspx

Comment: Nice to know. Next time I have to do this I'll give `ExecuteXmlReader` a try.

Comment: lol :) ...there shoud be a method called executeToAnything(string format),like xml,json,etc...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have to do this in C# (i.e. you can't use an external tool, which I think would be the best solution), you can use [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) to read the table sequentially and output each record individually. The disadvantage is that it's going to require some hand-written XML code.

The general idea is to create an [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then create an `SqlDataReader` by calling `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`, then reading one record at a time. As you read each record, you output it to the `XmlWriter`:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings{ ... initialization here };
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFilename, settings)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("record");
        writer.WriteElementString("field1", record[0].ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("field2", record[1].ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

It's rather a pain in the neck, but it works well and the memory footprint is pretty small.