# Is there a faster way to generate XML Files

Tags: c#, xml, optimization

I am generating a XML file with hundreds of thousands of elements and the runtime of my code is currently over 3 minutes! I have tried both `XDocument` and `XmlDocument` to see if either would decrease the runtime; `XDocument` was better, but only by a small margin. Is there anything else I can try?

Code

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/employee.xml");

XDocument d = new XDocument(new XElement("Employees"));
d.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true");

while (reader.Read())
{
    d.Root.Add(new XElement("Employee",
        new XElement("LastName", reader["lastname"].ToString()),
        new XElement("FirstName", reader["firstname"].ToString()),
        new XElement("MiddleInitial", reader["middleini"].ToString()),
        new XElement("ID", reader["id"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Title", reader["title"].ToString()),
        new XElement("DOB", reader["title"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Category", reader["category"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Supervisor", reader["supervisor"].ToString()),
        new XElement("CurrentAddress", reader["address1"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Address", reader["address2"].ToString()),
        new XElement("City", reader["city"].ToString()),
        new XElement("State", reader["state"].ToString()),
        new XElement("ZipCode", reader["zip"].ToString()),
        new XElement("OfficePhone", reader["office_phone"].ToString()),
        new XElement("HomePhone", reader["home_phone"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Email", reader["email_address"].ToString()),
        new XElement("DateHired", reader["chem_employment_date"].ToString()),
        new XElement("DateTerminated", reader["emp_terminate_date"].ToString()),
        new XElement("StatusCode", reader["status_code"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Room", reader["room"].ToString()),
        new XElement("IsPrivate", reader["isprivate"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Floor", reader["floor"].ToString()),
        new XElement("Wing", reader["wing"].ToString()),
        new XElement("InRoster", reader["isroster"].ToString()),
        new XElement("RosterCategory", reader["roster_category"].ToString()),
        new XElement("LastModified", reader["lastmodified"].ToString()),
        new XElement("ShowReport", reader["isbudget"].ToString()),
        new XElement("ModifiedBy", reader["lastmodifiedby"].ToString())
    ));
    d.Save(path);
}
```

Comment: Maybe move d.Save() out of the while loop? Right now, you're writing the document to disk every time you add a new element.

Comment: What is the real source of the data?

Comment: @NicholasHunter that worked rather well! Thank you, in all of the documentation I was reading, they had the `document.Save()` inside the loop.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky the source of the data is an oracle database

Comment: I'm assuming that your _hundreds of thousands_ of elements is the result of many input rows generating about the 20-something elements you show above, fives of thousands of times. Instead of using something like `reader["isbudget"]` for every read into the DataReader, go look up the ordinals for each column and use them instead. You could use a normal mapper (like in Dapper), you could write a mapper, or you could just start off (outside your per-row loop) getting something like `var isBudgetOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("isbudget") and then using the ordinals.  Many string lookups get expensive

Comment: @Flydog57 when trying to implement this, I get an error `System.InvalidCastException: Column contains NULL data`. Does this mean that I have to check each element to see if it is null, or is there another way to do it. My current implementation is `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("isbudget"))`

Comment: Doing `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("isbudget"))` buys you nothing but extra code.  Pull the call to `reader.GetOrdinal` out of the loop and then read the DataReader using the ordinal.  Outside loop, use `var isBudgetOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("isbudget");` and then within the loop, `reader[isBudgetOrdinal]?.ToString()??string.Empty` (the null propagation bits (`?.` and `??`) should take care of nulls).  Where you not getting null issues with the code you had?

Comment: I think the code is great.  Only issue is results is not well formed since you have an array at the root of the xml.  I would add a top level element Employees so you only have one element at the root.

Comment: Something faster than XML is JSON. Btw, try reading DB data to the object data model (even using ORM), then serialize it to XML (JSON/CSV/anything) at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the xmlwriter class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=net-5.0

[C# export of large datatbase to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664960/c-sharp-export-of-large-datatbase-to-xml)

XmlWriter uses less memory than XmlDocument, but you will have to write the entire document from scratch each time.